# Опять же htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Нужна помощь в таком вопросе. В cms параметры сейчас обрабатываются через парсинг массива GET, то есть из формы посылаются запросы `method=GET`. При отправке формы поиска, урлы имеют следующий вид:

`http://myweb.com/controller/method/?age=3&season=5`

Отловить GET в контроллере легко, но у меня стоит вопрос: как из формы их сразу можно посылать в виде `http://myweb.com/controller/method/age3/season5`, а затем в контроллере парсить `age3/season5`? Я так понял, что переписать в такой урл на лету может htaccess - то есть параметры из формы передаются `?age=3?&season=5`, а htaccess его меняет на `age3/season5` или я не правильно понимаю работу htaccess?

Файл htaccess, который сейчас используется:

> AddDefaultCharset utf-8
>
> RewriteEngine on RewriteBase /
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} 
>   !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}
>   !-d RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l 
>   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php

Comment: По сути это банальный ЧПУ (человеко-подобный урл), современные cms (например, друпал, вордпресс) не делают редиректы на уровне htaccess на ЧПУ, контроллер сам формирует ЧПУ и разбирает его на аргументы.

Comment: Ну то есть я правильно понимаю что нужно отловить get отпарсить  его собрать в нужный вид и сделать редирект?

Comment: если уже на сайте все адреса будут ЧПУ, - зачем делать редирект?

Comment: Я не пойму,  как из формы отправить их  в таком виде?и В форме где выбирают цвет размер, как ? Каким методом? Сделать js который будет собирать параметры формы в  урл ??!

Comment: отправьте POST, на сервере сформируйте ЧПУ и отдайте страницу пользователю.

Comment: Пользователь пришел на сайте по адресу, myweb.com/product ввел параметры нажал отправить скрипт ловит POST обрабатывает формирует урл /param1/param2 и через header(Location:myweb.com/product/param1/param2) отдает юзеру, так?!

Comment: Думаю [в этой ссылке](http://rapidup.ru/stati/Htaccess_RewriteRule_primery.html) достаточно подробно описано ваше решение